# Menu links to media library items

Tags: media, navigation

Is it possible to link to media library items such as documents and images rather than be restricted to content nodes?

Fairly new to Drupal development and thought this would be fairly standard but struggling to find a clear direction. Looking to generate links to certain documents within a mixed menu but the option is not found when searching, only generated content pages are returned as matches under the 'Link' field for 'Add menu link' rather than any media items.

Looked at a number of modules to extend the capability but nothing is achieving being able to link to media items in the same way as content pages which would be maintainable. Sure could copy and paste a link manually but this does not feel right way to do it.

UPDATE

Tried Linkit and can get links to media entities such as images and documents which works fine for CKeditor. However, I cannot see how I could utilise this to search and select items to generate menu links for anything other than content pages. I feel I am missing something obvious.

Comment: We can't know what you expect :-) You can enter any link like `/media/NUMERIC_MEDIA_ID` in that field, even if media is not suggested by search. For a custom, configurable UI look at [Linkit module](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkit)

Comment: LinkIt will do this.

Comment: Thank you. Simply looking for a link inserted into the menu to the document or image instead of to a page. Will take a look at Linkit.

Comment: I cannot see how I can apply this to anything other than CKeditor so I just be missing something.